# How to stop Jenkins installed on Mac Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, jenkins, daemon

I have installed Jenkins executable on OSX, but now I want to stop it running. Whenever I kill it, no matter how, it just restarts immediately.

I've tried using the exit command on the jenkins url:

```
http://localhost:8080/exit
```

which asks me to post the command, which I do, and the server shuts down as requested. *But then it restarts.*

I've tried searching for the process id using `ps`, and force killing it (`kill -9 pid`), and the server shuts down immediately, as requested. *But then it restarts.*

I've tried shutting it down via the gui, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

There must be a daemon somewhere, making this a general OSX question.

Comment: Can you tell me which command you used to stop it.
I used http://jettyserver/exit but seems it is not working.

Comment: Hey @JigneshSheth I used daniel's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8008901/150371)

Comment: UI --> jenkins --> manage jenkins --> prepare for shutdown   OR   brew services stop jenkins --all

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Just unload the plist using launchctl

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Comment: If in case you want to again have your jenkins started.. just use the reverse of the above --- `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

Comment: Works fine on 10.8.4, and I suspect it'll work forever with minor tweaks.

Answer (score 34):

For 1.505 you can use web api

```
http://localhost:8080/exit
http://localhost:8080/restart
http://localhost:8080/reload
```

Comment: I really needed a more direct way to kill Jenkins since I couldn't kill the process via the command line. Thanks!

Comment: This really doesn't work. On OSX the jenkins server is immediately restarted by a daemon.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Maybe things have changed

Comment: Time report: Unfortunately it's still the same :(

Comment: Using this method, I'm getting the error: "This URL requires POST"

Answer (score 14):

- Start Jenkins service: `brew services start jenkins-lts`
- Stop Jenkins service: `brew services stop jenkins-lts`
- Restart Jenkins service: `brew services restart jenkins-lts`

Comment: Perfect. This has helped me! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There are two things going on.

(1) will your system start Jenkins when it comes up. Controlled by load and unload.

(2) Is Jenkins currently running or not.  Controlled by start and stop.

## Jenkins unload stops it and it won't load again on boot up

sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist

## stop it without unloading it ( will load again when you reboot)

sudo launchctl stop  /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist

## load it - starts it and will restart whenever your system boots

sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist

## restarts it,  doesn't effect loaded or unloaded status

sudo launchctl start /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist

Answer (score 3):

I had to unload/load the **LaunchAgents**:

sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist

sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist

I'm on Sierra (10.12.3).

Answer (score 1):

Note, that if you wish also to disable running Jenkins on Mac OS start up,  according to http://halyph.blogspot.ru/2013/03/jenkins-on-mac-os-x-tips-and-tricks.html you should do:

> sudo defaults write /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci RunAtLoad -bool NO

UPD: didn't work for me (

Answer (score 1):

use `launchctl unload /Users/<user>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
2. UI -> jenkins --> manage jenkins --> prepare for shutdown
3. brew services stop jenkins --all

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins commands for Mac for M1 and Intel

```
Start Jenkins service   : brew services start jenkins-lts
Stop Jenkins service    : brew services stop jenkins-lts
Restart Jenkins service : brew services restart jenkins-lts
```