# Can not run Jenkins on Mac

Tags: macos, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I have downloaded Mac OS X native package from Jenkins [web site](http://jenkins-ci.org/), installed it, opened my browser at http://localhost:8080/ and got error page with this text:

```
Status Code: 404
Exception: Request URL / not found.<br><br>
Stacktrace:
Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Tue Nov 29 12:00:52 CET 2011
```

I have found `jenkins.war` in `/Applications/Jenkins` and tried running it with `java -jar jenkins.war`:

```
$ pwd
/Applications/Jenkins


$ ls
jenkins.war

$ java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
[Winstone 2011/11/29 12:03:12] - Beginning extraction from war file
Jenkins home directory: /Users/zeljko/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
[Winstone 2011/11/29 12:03:16] - Winstone shutdown successfully
[Winstone 2011/11/29 12:03:16] - Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpListener
    at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:250)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:202)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:398)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at Main._main(Main.java:268)
    at Main.main(Main.java:96)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to listen on port 8080
    at winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:117)
    at winstone.HttpListener.start(HttpListener.java:70)
    at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:241)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:112)
    ... 10 more

Nov 29, 2011 12:03:16 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins$6 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Nov 29, 2011 12:03:16 PM hudson.WebAppMain$2 run
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:244)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:816)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:730)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:217)
```

Since the error message says `Address already in use` I have tried running it on another port:

```
$ java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081
Running from: /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
[Winstone 2011/11/29 12:11:26] - Beginning extraction from war file
Jenkins home directory: /Users/zeljko/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
[Winstone 2011/11/29 12:11:27] - HTTP Listener started: port=8081
[Winstone 2011/11/29 12:11:27] - Winstone shutdown successfully
[Winstone 2011/11/29 12:11:27] - Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.ajp13.Ajp13Listener
    at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:250)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:203)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:398)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at Main._main(Main.java:268)
    at Main.main(Main.java:96)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to listen on port 8009
    at winstone.ajp13.Ajp13Listener.start(Ajp13Listener.java:92)
    at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:241)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at winstone.ajp13.Ajp13Listener.start(Ajp13Listener.java:87)
    ... 9 more

Nov 29, 2011 12:11:27 PM jenkins.model.Jenkins$6 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Nov 29, 2011 12:11:27 PM hudson.WebAppMain$2 run
SEVERE: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:244)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:816)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:730)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:77)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$2.run(WebAppMain.java:217)
```

But I get `Address already in use` error message, it does not matter which port I try.

I have stopped Firewall, just in case (System Preferences > Security > Firewall > Stop). It did not help.

I have copied `jenkins.war` to `/Users/zeljko/Jenkins` and tried running it with `java -jar jenkins.war` and `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081`. The same error messages.

I have downloaded [Latest and greatest (1.441) jenkins.war](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/latest/jenkins.war) from the web site, moved it to `/Users/zeljko/Jenkins`, and tried  `java -jar jenkins.war` and `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081`. The same error messages.

Environment:

Mac OS X 10.6.8

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-10M3527)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)
```

I am browsing Jenkins [web site](http://jenkins-ci.org/), [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Home), [book](http://www.wakaleo.com/books/jenkins-the-definitive-guide), searching around, but I just do not get what I have to do to get it working.

Comment: Since this is not relevant any more (fixed in the current versions, right?), would you consider closing the issue. Personally, I got Jenkins up easily doing 'brew install jenkins'.

Comment: @akauppi: how do I "close" a stack overflow question?

Comment: @akauppi: feel free to move you comment to an answer, and if it gets more votes than the currently accepted answer, I will mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue appears to have been added to Jenkins' Jira, and hopefully will be fixed soon: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11714?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

On my 10.7.2 installation I've made it work by creating the missing Home folder and changing the owner of the Jenkins.

After installing Jenkins, run the following commands:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home
sudo chown -R daemon /Users/Shared/Jenkins
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not find that Jira ticket while looking around.

Comment: BTW ... or FWIT ... the latest Mac Installer creates the Directory and also creates a Hidden user called Jenkins so you don't need to do this.  BUT ... you can still get the same error when the Directory is not there (ie if you delete /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home )

Answer (score 8):

This fixed the problem:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

After that I could run `java -jar jenkins.war` at `/Users/zeljko/Jenkins`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8008901/17469

Answer (score 7):

ajp tries to listen on 8009. It looks like you got tomcat running (hence 8080 and 8009 are already occupied). Turn ajp off when starting Jenkins.

Start with:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081 --ajp13Port=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the mistake was to install Mac OS X native package. I have tried running `java -jar jenkins.war` on a machine where I just downloaded `jenkins.war`, and it works fine. Now to see how to get the native package running or uninstalled...

Comment: looks like this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474835/configure-jenkins-mac-os-x-native-package-to-run-in-a-different-port

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly caused by the 8080 port is used by other process(in most case it's a tomcat java process). 
So at first, you should execute:

```
lsof -i:8080
```

Then kill the process who is using port 8080.

After that, execute your command again.

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8081
```